# Software or web app to find the source of an animated GIF

Tags: images, search-engine

What software or website can I use to find the source of a GIF?

For example, https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkfTU.jpg (the people in it look very familiar).

I tried to use [Google Reverse Image Search](https://www.google.com/imghp), but it said "The URL doesn't refer to an image, or the image is not publicly accessible."

Comment: If you need to support animated GIF, like your example, you might want to state that.  For static images, I prefer https://tineye.com to anything that Google offers. Of course, all that any such tool can offer is a list of all sites hosting the image. It cannot say definitively which is the source, although you may be able to sort on date.